# Assigning to Double from incompatible type?

Tags: c++, arrays, function, structure

New to programming, having trouble to pass array to function using struct. any ideas? compiler generating error "Assigning to Double from incompatible type weather". 
 thanks in advance/

```
  struct Weather
   {
       double TotalRainfall[12];
       double HTemperature[12];
       double LTemperature[12];
       double AverageTemperature[12];

   };

    Weather AverageTemp(Weather *W, int size)
    {

        for(int i = 1;i<=12;i++)
        {
           return W[i].HTemperature[i]+W[i].LTemperature[i];


        }

    }

    int main()
    {
        Weather W[12];
        int size =12;

        for(int i = 1;i<=12;i++)
        {
            cout << "Enter Total Rainfall in " << i << " month";
            cin >> W[i].TotalRainfall[i];

            cout << " Enter the highest temperature " << i << " month";
            cin >> W[i].HTemperature[i];

            cout << " Enter the Lowest temperature " << i << " month";
            cin >> W[i].LTemperature[i];


        }

         for(int i = 1;i<=12;i++)
         {
             W[i].AverageTemperature[i]=  AverageTemp(W, size);
         }
```

Comment: Look at your code.  What does `AverageTemp()` return?  What is `W[i].HTemperature[i]`?  Do you think that should work?

Comment: In your function `AverageTemp(..)` you defined it to return a `Weather` struct, but in your `return` statement you are returning `double`. 

Also, in your `for.. loop`, the whole function will finish on the first iteration.. (possible logic error there)!

Comment: Also, an array with K elements is indexed from 0 to K-1.

Comment: I believe you should either have only one `Weather` containing arrays with twelve entries *or* twelve `Weather`s, each containing the information for only one month.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several mistakes in your code.  Lets start with the error of assigning double from incompatible type.  `AverageTemp` in your example is a method that returns a `Weather` type.  I assume you meant to return a double value.

Another problem is that you're inputting total rainfall, highest and lowest temperature plus average temperature for each month.  By my measure that's 12*4 or 48 doubles that you'll need.  Instead you have an array of 12 `Weather` structs, each containing 48 doubles each or 576 doubles!  I'm guessing you didn't intend for that, so I simplified your example to use just one `Weather` struct.  Now we're using one `Weather` instance and passing that instance to `AverageTemp` as a reference (so we don't make a copy).

Third problem is a little more subtle, but you would have surely have discovered it after you fixed the previous two.  You cannot access the nth element of an array of n by using an index n.  In other words, the 1st element is accessed with index *0* because arrays are accessed from zero onwards.  Meaning for every loop with i starting at 1 and ending at 12 would have resulted in an ugly error on number 12 because the *13th* element isn't there in your array.  Most programmers let the index variable start at 0 and count up to but not equal to the limit, so you never have to worry about going over.  I compensated display of month number as a result.

The new code is below:

```
// ...

double AverageTemp(Weather &w, int index)
{
    return (w.HTemperature[index]+w.LTemperature[index])/2.0;
}

int main()
{
    Weather w;
    int size =12;

    for(int i = 0;i<12;i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter Total Rainfall in " << i+1 << " month" << endl;
        cin >> w.TotalRainfall[i];

        cout << " Enter the highest temperature " << i+1 << " month" << endl;
        cin >> w.HTemperature[i];

        cout << " Enter the Lowest temperature " << i+1 << " month" << endl;
        cin >> w.LTemperature[i];
    }

    for(int i = 0;i<12;i++)
    {
        w.AverageTemperature[i]=  AverageTemp(w, i);
    }
}
```

If you have any questions please *ask*!  It is important that you understand these concepts rather than have working code because it will serve you better in the future.